# JDBC Driver: Converts Standard API calls to low level calls

Tags: java, api, jdbc, driver

I'm newbie in JDBC and I was studying about JDBC Driver and I saw this definition of JDBC Driver:

> JDBC Driver converts Standard API calls to low level calls.

What are low level calls and standard api calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Standard API" calls are those defined by the JDBC API, basically all the types defined in the [`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) package.

"Low level" calls are whatever calls the JDBC driver need to make in order to actually "communicate" with the database, e.g.

- An Oracle OCI driver needs to call the OCI library directly.
- An Oracle Thin driver needs to communicate over TCP/IP with the database server.
  SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc works like this too.
- Embedded database drivers like H2, HSQLDB, Derby, etc. needs to call the Java code implementing the database.

Answer (score 1):

A JDBC driver is used to enable interaction between Java and a database. Each database will have his own driver to interact with the corresponding protocol.

Each JDBC driver are basically translating standard [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) calls into native database calls.

(It's a little more complex in reality, if you want all details take at look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_1_driver_%E2%80%93_JDBC-ODBC_bridge))

Comment: you mean "low level calls" are native database calls?